# When rig moves mesh the mesh seems to duplicate

Tags: mesh, rigging, rigify

I have used rigify and produced a rig that moves my mesh. When the mesh moves in pose mode it seems to duplicate everywhere aside from at the point it is being moved. Additionally the underlying armature skeleton does not seem to move for some reason? I am sure I am missing something basic here but would appreciate any insight regarding what that might be? [image]

Comment: Additionally, while this model is not intended to be sexual in any manner, but it is supposed to represent an anatomical correct male body. While I don't think the mesh is particularly graphic it might warrant a very mild NSFW warning. It hasn't been shaded or coloured at all I just wanted to give a heads up!

Comment: it tends to freeze but I was able to open it, actually your object has thickness (mesh within the mesh), it's going to be hard to remove, have you applied a Solidify modifier?

Comment: Hi moonboots, that is great to hear. No I have not tried doing this.

Comment: I meant the thickness may come from a Solidify that you applied, the problem now is how to delete the inner mesh, or you need to give some correction in Weight Paint mode

Comment: I did end up converting the mesh to tris nd then tris to quads because I've heard non-poly shapes can be challenging to animate. Could this have come from that?

Comment: You have a lot of tris here, the topology is not good, if you plan to animate, keep it low poly, with a Subdivision Surface modifier, but it doesn't explain why you have thickness, as I said it may be a Solidify modifier that you've applied, do you have a previous version of your object + armature?

Comment: <img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=x6OjAJ58" />

Comment: This should be it!

Comment: If you'd like I can also upload the original mesh

Comment: the link is not good, please give the correct link  ;)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=zEJZxawa" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/zEJZxawa/)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=x6OjAJ58" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/x6OjAJ58/)

Comment: both the 2 meshes you share have bad topology and thickness, so it will be tedious to correct and animate, don't you have the same with a simple topology (quads and less faces)?

Comment: Hmmm unfortunately I do not. I downloaded the original file from online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a double problem here, your topology is bad and it has thickness (as if a *Solidify* modifier has been applied), see the difference between a good and bad topology (image below): The first one has way less faces, they are mainly quads and they follow the anatomy, the second one (yours) has a lot of small and completely disorganized faces with a lot of tris (plus it has thickness as I said). It's going to be very tedious to correct and animate, in my opinion you should better find another object.

[image]

From your new mesh, see if I remove an edge out of 2, it won't change the general shape, so you can simplify it. Of course it also depends on if you can use the *Subdivision Surface* modifier or not (if you stay within Blender, you can keep it):

[image]

Comment: Awesome! I guess to confirm (so that I can understand better going forward) would something like this be a better mesh? Just to get an idea of what to look for! [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=okWKmAnK" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/okWKmAnK/)

Comment: Yes that kind of mesh, you could even remove some edges as they don't add any details.

Comment: Thank you for all of your constructive feedback!

Comment: you're welcome, I've edited my answer